# controlling an element from inside of another element in css

Tags: css, hover

hello there I'm facing now a problem with controlling an element from inside of a different element .
for example if I want to control the appearance of an element inside of footer by hovering over another element in header .
i hope you have the answer and thanks in advance

Comment: Please consider adding a code snippet for what you are trying to achieve. Also, show which environment you are using for development. This will help to get a focused answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is, for example, if you have a li with a link inside and you want to change the color of the link when the li is hovered on, you could do this:

```css
ul li:hover a {
  color: green;
}

/* only for presentation */
ul li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

if you wanted to affect totally random elements as you said, you can do this:

```css
/* ----- This is all extra styling ----- */
body {
  background-color: #121212;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgb(31, 33, 34);
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  background-color: rgb(31, 33, 34);
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
}
/* ----- This is all extra styling ----- */

.header:hover + .footer {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <!-- Meta tags and what not -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
        <!--Header stuff here-->
        <h2>My Website</h2>
    </div>
    <!--In this case the footer and header must be exactly next to eachother for the + to work-->
    <div class="footer">
      <h4>Hover on the header to change my color</h4>
    </div>
    
    <!--This could be whatever you want the page content to be-->
    <main>
    </main>
 </body>
</html>
```